# Populate ListView with AsyncTaskLoader in ListFragment

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

I'm trying to load some data in a ListView. The Fragment loads well, but the ListView is empty and no data its shown. I use a BaseAdapter as my adapter, and here it is:

```
public class PokedexAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    List<PokedexModel> dex;

    public PokedexAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public void setData(List<PokedexModel> data) {
        this.dex = data;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return dex == null ? 0 : dex.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return dex == null ? null : dex.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view;

        if (convertView == null) {
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_pokemon, parent, false);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }

        PokedexModel item = dex.get(position);
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.numero)).setText(item.getNum());
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.pokemon)).setText(item.getNombre());
        ((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.sprite)).setImageResource(item.getSprite());
        ((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.tipo1)).setImageResource(item.getTipo1());
        ((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.tipo2)).setImageResource(item.getTipo2());
        return view;
    }

}
```

And here is my fragment. It works well, but I only get `setEmptyText()`. I load the data from a XML in my raw folder. I tried the same method on another project and works perfectly.

```
public class Nacional extends Fragment {

    static Context ctx;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content) == null) {
            DataListFragment list = new DataListFragment();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, list).commit();
        }
    }

    public class DataListFragment extends ListFragment implements android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<PokedexModel>> {

        PokedexAdapter mAdapter;

        @Override public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            setEmptyText("No Kanto Pokédex available.");
            mAdapter = new PokedexAdapter(getActivity());
            setListAdapter(mAdapter);
            setListShown(false);
            getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
        }

        @Override
        public Loader<List<PokedexModel>> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
            return new DataListLoader(getActivity());
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<PokedexModel>> arg0, List<PokedexModel> data) {
            mAdapter.setData(data);
            if(isResumed())
                setListShown(true);
            else
                setListShownNoAnimation(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<PokedexModel>> arg0) {
            mAdapter.setData(null);
        }

    }

    public static class DataListLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<PokedexModel>> {

        List<PokedexModel> mModels;

        public DataListLoader(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStartLoading() {
            super.onStartLoading();
            if(mModels != null)
                deliverResult(mModels);

            if(takeContentChanged() || mModels == null)
                forceLoad();
        }

        @Override
        public List<PokedexModel> loadInBackground() {

            List<PokedexModel> dex = new ArrayList<PokedexModel>();
            try {
                InputStream is = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.data);
                DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = builder.parse(is, null);
                NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("pkmn");

                for (int i = 0; i < 151; i++) {
                    Element e = (Element) nodes.item(i);

                    dex.add(new PokedexModel(i + 1, Constantes.Pokemon[i], Constantes.Icons[i],
                            Constantes.Tipo[Integer.parseInt(Global.getValue(e, "type1"))],
                            Constantes.Tipo[Integer.parseInt(Global.getValue(e, "type2"))]));

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return dex;
        }

        @Override
        public void deliverResult(List<PokedexModel> listOfData) {
            if (isReset())
                if (listOfData != null)
                    onReleaseResources(listOfData);

            List<PokedexModel> oldDex = this.mModels;
            this.mModels = listOfData;

            if (isStarted())
                super.deliverResult(listOfData);

            if (oldDex != null)
                onReleaseResources(oldDex);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStopLoading() {
            cancelLoad();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCanceled(List<PokedexModel> data) {
            super.onCanceled(data);
            onReleaseResources(data);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onReset() {
            super.onReset();
            onStopLoading();
            if (mModels != null) {
                onReleaseResources(mModels);
                mModels = null;
            }
        }

        protected void onReleaseResources(List<PokedexModel> data) {

        }

    }

}
```

**EDIT**

Here's the model I use:

```
public class PokedexModel {

    private int num, sprite, tipo1, tipo2;
    private String nombre;

    public PokedexModel(int numero, String pokemon, int icono, int t1, int t2) {
        num = numero;
        nombre = pokemon;
        sprite = icono;
        tipo1 = t1;
        tipo2 = t2;
    }

    public void setNum(int n) {
        this.num = n;
    }

    public void setNombre(String n) {
        this.nombre = n;
    }

    public void setSprite(int s) {
        this.sprite = s;
    }

    public void setTipo1(int tipo1) {
        this.tipo1 = tipo1;
    }

    public void setTipo2(int tipo2) {
        this.tipo2 = tipo2;
    }

    public int getNum() {
        return this.num;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return this.nombre;
    }

    public int getSprite() {
        return this.sprite;
    }

    public int getTipo1() {
        return this.tipo1;
    }

    public int getTipo2() {
        return tipo2;
    }
```

And I tried to run this new code in `loadInBackground()` but I get an error:

```
PokedexModel entry = new PokedexModel(i + 1, Constantes.Pokemon[i], i, i, i);
dex.add(entry);
```

Thanks.

Comment: did you checked the method "public List<PokedexModel> loadInBackground()" really does populates the list? if not than thats the point to start from

Comment: @Stan I tried a different way, adding a single entry, but when I run the app there's an error. I edited my main post with my model and the new code.

Comment: You see the loadInBackground should return a POPULATED by PokedexModel objects list - List<PokedexModel>. If this method does not populate list and retunrs an empty list then there is an issue there. Did you ever checked if it returns populated list?